# Changing Git user on the fly

Tags: git, version-control, zsh, zshrc

I'd like to be able to switch the name and email in git, I tried this:

```
alias setup_diffuser='export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Blah" && export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="blah@blah.com" && export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Blah" && GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="blah@blah.com" && export BLAH="true"'
```

but the name in the git commit is correct but the email is the one in `~/.gitconfig` not the email in`$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` How can I set the email on the fly like above without editing the `~/.gitconfig`? I'm running git version 1.7.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot an export for `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` :

```
alias setup_diffuser='export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Blah" && export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="blah@blah.com" && export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Blah" && export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="blah@blah.com" && export blah="true"'
```